# about overstay in denmark

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, denmark

I have visited Denmark two times so far, and my husband lives there. The last time when I went there 8 year ago, I applied for a permanent visa, which was refused. I consequently overstayed for 10 days because I didn't receive a ticket for the return flight on time.

Now they do not even give me a visitor visa. I have two children holding danish nationality. I have tried to apply for visitor visa two times, but it was refused each time. **Now I want to try again to apply for a visit visa. Can you give any advise about it?** The marriage of my husband's son is going to held in august. I want to apply for a visitor visa to attend the marriage.

Your fast replies are highly appreciated.

Thanks, nabila mushtaq

Comment: You have already asked that question and received a good answer. We can't do much more than that and certainly can't make predictions, let alone tell you that the outcome will be positive. If you want more info, you should provide the details you have been asked for instead of posting a nearly identical question without even improving the formatting.

Comment: @Relaxed, I think the OP is looking for a silver bullet and the original answer did not give one, hence the new attempt.  The lack of silver bullets is a chronic problem for overstayers :)